# What is the recommended methodology for debugging Angular app that causes 'page unresponsive'?

Tags: angularjs

I am an AngularJS newbie. I have an AngularJS app that causes the browser to report 'Page has become unresponsive'. What are the steps I should take to debug and find what is causing this behavior?

(I am asking this way, rather than posting code and having someone solve my problem, so I can learn how to solve similar problems for myself in the future)

Comment: Start inspecting outputs of rendering body of page(s).

Answer (score 3):

you can check few things if page goes unresponsive

1. check the page [watch count](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef) or [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2698-counting-the-number-of-watchers-in-angularjs.htm) (I prefer implementation in link 2)
2. once you know the watch count, try reduce the watch count if its too much
3. can you use one-time binding (hence reducing the watchers) [read here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)
4. if you have ng-repeat and need two way binding & use [track by](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/optimizing-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided, I think that the error isn't related to `AngularJs` itself. You might see some information on [this site](http://customercenter.karthost.com/knowledgebase/125/Using-Google-Chrome---The-pages-have-become-unresponsive-Wait-or-Kill-message.html), which describes clearly how to solve this issue.

> What are the steps I should take to debug and find what is causing this behavior?

Typically, the most common way to debug `AngularJs` application is to use `Chrome Dev tools, inspect element`. It allows you to put any breakpoints in order to verify your application.

Alternatively, if you are using Chrome, you could use [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek) which is very great chrome extension to debug your `AngularJs` app.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at the resources you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `AngularJS` causes the browser to be unresponsive when there are too many watches.

There is a Chrome extension [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek?hl=en) that allows the inspection of each binded expression.

You can view the time required for each expression to load (both in ms and as a percentage of total application load).

Take a look at these articles:

- [Removing the Unneeded Watches](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/)
- [Debugging performance problems in AngularJS with Batarang and Chrome DevTools](http://daginge.com/technology/2013/08/11/debugging-performance-problems-in-angularjs-with-batarang/)

And at this module [BindOnce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).